# Cordova - Build Error with local-notification plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, notifications

Sorry I'm new in Cordova application creation.

1. I installed everything needed in order to develop a Mobile application with Cordova.
2. Cordova create notification
3. cd notification
4. cordova platform add android
5. cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git
6. cordova plugin ls

Result :

```
C:\LAB\Cordova\notification>cordova plugin ls
[ 'de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification',
  'org.apache.cordova.device' ]
```

Everything is fine at this time.
I follow the github readme file : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/README.md

*PhoneGap Build
Add the following xml to your config.xml to always use the latest version of this plugin:

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />*
```

then I add it in my config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
  <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />
</widget>
```

Then I add in the index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
<p class="event received" onclick="window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'Great app!' });">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="local-notification.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">]
        window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'Great app!' });
    </script>
</body>
```

I encounter this error when I launch a : Cordova build android

```
    BUILD FAILED
C:\ANDROID\android-sdk-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error
occurred while executing this line:
C:\ANDROID\android-sdk-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 10 seconds
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\LAB\Cordova\n
otification\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=a
nt-gen
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)

C:\LAB\Cordova\notification>cordova plugin ls
[ 'de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification',
  'org.apache.cordova.device' ]
```

Would someone explain to me how to properly implement a plugin in a working basic Cordova application ?

Thank you.
R

Comment: are you building this local or are you using the phone gap build website to build your project? if you are just using cordova build on your local machine then you do not need to add the reference to the config.xml file

Comment: Hi finally I updated the cordova and everything is working fine now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build fails when I add the latest version on local notification plugin using CLI Command failed with exit code 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452132/build-fails-when-i-add-the-latest-version-on-local-notification-plugin-using-cli)