# Build fails when I add the latest version on local notification plugin using CLI Command failed with exit code 8

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Below is the full error message

C:\joel1\joel1\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\localnotificatio
n\LocalNotification.java:495: error: cannot find symbol
                    webView.evaluateJavascript(js, null);
                           ^
  symbol:   method evaluateJavascript(String,)
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
C:\joel1\joel1\platforms\android\src\de\appplant\cordova\plugin\localnotificatio
n\LocalNotification.java:492: error: cannot find symbol
        webView.post(new Runnable(){
               ^
  symbol:   method post()
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
2 errors
:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.529 secs

C:\joel1\joel1\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\joel1\joel1\platforms\android
\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\joel1\joel1\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBui
ldArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: C:\joel1\joel1\platforms\andr
oid\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

Comment: file an issue on the plugin github repository so the developer can fix it

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is to modify the block starting at `LocalNotification.java:492` with the following:

```
webView.getView().post(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      webView.sendJavascript(js);
    } else {
      webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
    }
  }
});
```

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/535

Answer (score 0):

In platforms/android/src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/localnotification/LocalNotification.java file

```
private static synchronized void sendJavascript(final String js) {

    if (!deviceready) {
        eventQueue.add(js);
        return;
    }
    webView.getView().post(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
          webView.sendJavascript(js);
        } else {
          webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
        }
      }
    });
    // webView.post(new Runnable(){
    //     public void run(){
    //         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    //             webView.evaluateJavascript(js, null);
    //         } else {
    //             webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
    //         }
    //     }
    // });
}
```

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/426